# Xcode 7.3 can't find 'Project-Swift.h' file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, bridging-header, objective-c-swift-bridge

Assume my project is called "Project".
My actual project name does not have any spaces either, so that's not an issue.

I'm aware that to use a Swift file in Obj-C, you can add `Project-Swift.h` to the .m file.

However, I get a `'Project-Swift.h' file note found` error.

I've checked my Build Settings and in both the Target and the Project made sure the Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name on both of those is explicitly `Project-Swift.h`.

Additionally, again, on both the Target and the Project Build Settings I switched "Defines Module" to Yes.

I've also tried completely deleting the objective c file that I'm trying to make this import statement on, then creating a new one and copy and pasting the code in in case it was some issue with the project.pbxproj file.

Even though I don't need to use Obj-C code in Swift, I tried creating a `Project-Bridging-Header.h" and made sure it's referenced correctly in the Swift Compile Build Settings for both the target and the project.

So to follow up on that I don't have any circular references or anything that would require a forward declaration.

All of this seems to be in vain.

What am I missing?

Comment: try with `#import <Project-Swift.h>`

Answer (score -2):

Add an import to the location of the .h file in objective-c class.

Just import in .h file:

```
#import <Project-Swift.h>
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.